# export azure ml studio designer project as jupyter notebook?

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I hope I am not missing something obvious here. I am using the new azure ml studio designer. I am able to use to create datasets, train models and use them just fine.

azure ml studio allows creation of Jupyter notebooks (also) and use them to do machine learning. I am able to do that too.

So, now, I am wondering, can I build my ML pipeline/experiment in ML studio designer, and once it is in good shape, export it as a python and jupyter notebook? then, use it in the same designer provided notebook option or may be use it locally?

Comment: question: what would local use of the pipeline enable you to do? What would you like that the Studio Designer does not currently provide?

Comment: I would not want a local use at all. I would like to be able to take the designer based flow and turn that into a jupyter based notebook that I can just run on the same designer studio.

Comment: so are you interested in just being able to *trigger* the pipeline you made in the UI from a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: nothing about triggering. I want a total conversion. for example, say you have a pdf file. and you want that in word. so, designer is like pdf. jupyter notebook is like word document. I want a total conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not currently supported, but I am 80% sure it is in the roadmap.
An alternative would be to use the SDK to create the same pipeline using `ModuleStep` where  I *believe* you can reference a Designer Module by its name to use it like a `PythonScriptStep`

Comment: I will look into the Modulestep and see where that takes me.

Answer (score 5):

The export Designer graph to notebook is in our roadmap. For now, please take a look at the ModuleStep in SDK and let us know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Lu Zhang | Senior Program Manager | Azure Machine Learning

Comment: awesome. I will keep an eye out for that I will definitely be looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the instructions to Use the studio to [deploy models trained in the designer - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-model-designer) and document that explains how we can get access to score.py and conda_env.yaml files under Output + logs tab for Train module.