# is there a way to export experiments from on azure ml designer workspace to another?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

is there a way to export experiments from an azure ml designer workspace to another? Like moving changes from INT to QA to PROD

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306240/export-azure-ml-studio-designer-project-as-jupyter-notebook). Lu Zhang's and Anders' answers indicate that exporting the designer is on the roadmap, but not supported at that time.

Alternatively

Check out the [Create reproducible ML pipelines section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-model-management-and-deployment#create-reproducible-ml-pipelines) of the [documentation on MLOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-model-management-and-deployment) by Microsoft.

Specifically for the designer tool it recommends to click `...` at the top right of the designer and select `Clone` to save a copy of your design as a specific verion that would go through the QA Process.